# Where the a class instance will be located on memory if it is declared as A a?

Tags: c++, c, class, object

If declare an instance of  class A :
"A a;"
which kind of memory type will it be created on? 
any other type of memory type?

My solution:

It depends on where it is declared. 
If it is a global variable, and outside any class and functions, it is on heap. 
If it in a class or function, it is on stack. 
If is in a namespace, it is on heap .

right?

Answer (score 3):

Your question assumes that the only two answers are "stack" and "heap".

All variables declared outside of a function or class/union live in *global memory*. Which is why they're commonly called "globals". That memory is created by the loading of the executable, and the constructor to those classes is called before `main` executes (and the destructor is called after `main`).

If you declare a variable inside of a function, then it is on the stack. The only way something gets into the "heap" is if you allocate it explicitly with `new`, or if it is a member of some other object that was itself allocated.

Members of a class/union live wherever variables of them are declared.

Answer (score 2):

If it's local to a function, it's on the stack. If it's global or static, it's in the executable's data segment (AAKA "global memory"). If it's a declaration within another class, could be anywhere depending on how the instance of the class is allocated.

Namespace does not affect anything. It's just for the compiler.

EDIT re: classes.

If an instance is declared `A a;`, and this declaration happens to be inside a class, like this:

```
class B
{
    A a;
};
```

then the memory placement of `a` is determined by the way an enclosing instance of `B` is allocated. For example, in case of `B b;` the same rules apply - either stack or global memory. If it's

B *b = new B();

, however, then your `A` lives on the heap together with the rest of the `B`.

Comment: if it is declared inside a class, what factors can impact the allocations ? please show some examples. thanks

Comment: @Jack In this case it just depends on the specific instance of the class, for which again the same rules hold.

Comment: Also note that the compiler is allowed to move things wherever it pleases, as long as it pretends it did it by the rules.  For instance, the compiler is allowed to place local arrays on the heap, or in rare cases, global memory.